# How the parameters get passed in django

Tags: python, django, function

I have a simple question on how the `self` or the `obj` is being retrieved in python. I have this function:

```
def amount_invested_formatted(self, obj):
        value = '$' + intcomma(int(obj.invested))
        return value

    amount_invested_formatted.short_description = "AMOUNT INVESTED"
```

and many others just like it. I call the function on the `list_display` like so:

```
class InvestmentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = InvestmentResource
    list_display = ('amount_invested_formatted',)
    list_display_links = ( 'amount_invested_formatted',)

    def amount_invested_formatted(self, obj):
        value = '$' + intcomma(int(obj.invested))
        return value

    amount_invested_formatted.short_description = "AMOUNT INVESTED"
```

It works but I don't know where or how `self` and `obj` got passed. I know from [here](https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/#modifying-a-change-list-using-list_display) that:

> The list_display attribute of an admin.ModelAdmin object specifies
> what columns are shown in the change list. This value is a tuple of
> attributes of the object being modeled.

But it's still not clear what `self` or `obj` are since from reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp), python functions are straightforward on the parameters but what's above is not.

So can anyone show me what's happening here? Appreciate the answers.

Comment: [As per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display): "A string representing a ModelAdmin method that accepts one argument, the model instance...". It's a ModelAdmin method so `self` is implied to be the ModelAdmin instance and the second argument is the model instance

Comment: Also, even though they are declared the same way using the `def` keyword, there are differences between functions, instance methods, class methods and static methods.